# Is there a standard solution for Gauss Elimination in Fortran?

Tags: fortran

i'm gonna do a standard gauss elimination procedure in Fortran, and was wondering if there was some ready to go solutions already there? Preferrably in the shape of a function. I've looked in a number of fortran numeric books, but there seem there isn't any good solution theres.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the [LAPACK](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) subroutine [`DGETRF`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d0/d39/_v_a_r_i_a_n_t_s_2lu_2_r_e_c_2dgetrf_8f.html). This performs a LU-decomposition. The "U" part of the LU-decomposition corresponds to the solution of the Gauss elimination.

Note that with all LAPACK/BLAS routines, the first letter corresponds to the data type... See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lapack) for details.